# split items in list

Tags: python, list, split

How can I turn the following list

```
['1','2','A,B,C,D','7','8']
```

into

`['1','2','A','B','C','D','7','8']`

in the most pythonic way?

I have very unpythonic code that creates nested list, and then flatterens:

```
sum ( [ word.split(',') for word in words ], [] )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
result = [item for word in words for item in word.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain

In [2]: lis=['1','2','A,B,C,D','7','8']


In [5]: list(chain(*(x.split(',') for x in lis)))
Out[5]: ['1', '2', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '7', '8']
```

to further reduce the unwanted `split()` calls:

```
In [7]: list(chain(*(x.split(',') if ',' in x else x for x in lis)))
Out[7]: ['1', '2', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '7', '8']
```

using `map()`:

```
In [8]: list(chain(*map(lambda x:x.split(','),lis)))
Out[8]: ['1', '2', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '7', '8']

In [9]: list(chain(*map(lambda x:x.split(',') if ',' in x else x,lis)))
Out[9]: ['1', '2', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '7', '8']
```

Comment: -0.  All of these take almost twice as long as J.F. Sebastian's much cleaner `result = [item for word in words for item in word.split(',')]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      k=k=['1','2','A,B,C,D','7','8']
      m=[i for v in k for i in v if i!=","]
```